# Velocity 2.0 unable to find template resource in jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, velocity

I work with Velocity 2.0 in Spring Boot 5 to send email. I load templates from src/main/resources/email/ and define VelocityEngine as bean in config.xml file

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">file</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.path">src/main/resources/templates/email/</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval">5</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Every thing works fine when I run it from Intellij IDEA but when I build jar to run it on server it throws the exception:
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'MyTemplate.vm'. Any idea how to fix it? I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're using the FileResourceLoader and giving it a relative path of "src/main/resources/templates/email/"

So unless that path relative to where your application runs is on the server, it's giving you a perfectly reasonable error code.

What you want to be doing using the [ClasspathResourceLoader](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ClasspathResourceLoader.html) on your bean config and making sure that your templates are packaged appropriately in the resulting jar.

Comment: I've changed FileResourceLoader to ClasspathResourceLoader, moved my templates to src/main/resources and defined file.resource.loader.path as: <prop key="file.resource.loader.path">classpath</prop>. After that it starts to work with a jar. But I still need to save my templates in separate directory /email (I'll have a lot of templates) not in src/main/resources

Comment: By reading the documentation.  The documentation notes that ClassPathResource loader is a configuration free loader, resources only need to be on the classpath.  file.resource.loader.path no longer influences anything.  putting your templates in "src/main/resources/templates/email/" then you load them from as "/templates/email/my-email-template.vtl"